# JHIPSTER - How can I show a different HOME page in JHipster for each ROLE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I'm making a `JHipster` project and I need to show a different home page for each role that I log in with, I'm using `Angular 1.x.`

For example I have the `ROLE_ADMIN`and the `ROLE_USER`and I need to show a different dashboard for each on.

I have read that I can put something like this in the `home.controller.js`

```
  this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', (message) => {
            this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
                if (account.authorities.indexOf("ROLE_ADMIN") >=0)
                {
                    this.router.navigate(['#/pages/prueba/prueba.html']);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.account = account;
                }
            }); 
         });
```

But I can't make it work, it shows this error: `Error: this is undefined`

Anyone have a clue about this?

Comment: I guess you're a beginner in JS, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work  to understand,why `this`is undefined in your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `auth.service.js`. There is a method called `authorize`, which in turn calls `authThen`. These methods are invoked after the user is authenticated and normally redirects the user to the last state (normally the protected state that failed, since the user was not authenticated and therefore was redirected to the login). You may change the code here to redirect the user according to its authorities.
The same methods (`authorize` and `authThen`) are also called everytime before a state changes, because it is a "resolve" for each state (have a look at the `app.state.js`).

Another option would be to add an "onEnter" function to your state definition that redirects to the appropiate view.